# 70s-80s sci-fi collection with aliens and a girl werewolf who may have eaten cats

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, werewolf

There was a sci-fi collection book in my grade school library (1979). I believe it had 3 stories in it, but I might be wrong:

- One of them I believe was about a girl who was turning into a werewolf.
- There was also another story that had aliens of some sort in it.
- I cannot remember the 3rd story OR the cover!

I also remember a boy (or young teen) and possibly a cat in one story? Or maybe the werewolf was eating cats?

Comment: To help us help you, go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answer as many questions as you can, editing them into your question. As it stands, your question doesn't really have many details to latch onto.

Comment: Could it be operation chaos https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Chaos_(novel) by Paul Anderson? It had several parts, a werewolf and were tiger. Also a mix of magic and wwii.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [“Miles, Mutants and Microbes”](https://vorkosigan.fandom.com/wiki/Miles,_Mutants_and_Microbes) of the Vorkosigan verse by Lois McMaster Bujold.

1. 3 parts - check
2. Werewolf/cat eating - possibly. There’s a werewolf like mutant that’s more catlike and has a voracious appetite. It also eats rats.
3. The hero is a small man.
4. Aliens - One story is about mutants with four hands

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/61885.Miles_Mutants_and_Microbes):

> *Falling Free*—The Nebula Award-winning novel. Leo Graf was just your typical efficient engineer: mind your own business and do the job. But all that changed on his assignment to the Cay Habitat, where children had been bio-engineered to have four arms (and no legs) to function in zero gravity. Now that they’re no longer needed, a heartless mega corporation is getting rid of them before they eat into the profit margin. Leo Graf adopted 1000 quaddies—now he had to teach them to be free.
>
> “Labyrinth”—When Miles Vorkosigan is captured while on a secret mission to a lawless world, his only hope of escape is an unlikely pair of allies: a quaddie and a teenage werewolf.
>
> *Diplomatic Immunity*— Miles Vorkosigan and his wife were heading home for the births of their first children, but a major diplomatic disaster is looming at Graf Station, colonized by the descendants of the original quaddies, and duty calls. Unfortunately, diplomatic immunity doesn’t carry over to immunity from a very nasty biological weapon. The downside of being a troubleshooter comes when trouble starts shooting back. . .